# How to set video deinterlacing with libVLCSharp for Windows?

Tags: libvlcsharp

I'm using libVLCSharp for Windows. Is there a way to set video deinterlacing mode with libVLCSharp? Thanks.

Tried the following

```
    media.AddOption(":deinterlace=1");
    media.AddOption(":video-filter=deinterlace");
    media.AddOption(":deinterlace-mode=blend");
```

From the vlc log this code does not seem to work. Any advice? Thanks.

Comment: Correction: media.AddOption(":deinterlace=on");

Comment: welcome to the community!  When you need to do any fixes/corrections, reformatting, or add something, you can do so by clicking `Edit` at the bottom left of your question.  Take care.

Answer (score 1):

If the deinterlace parameters are passed when initializing LibVLC, it works. For example

```
  string[] options = { "--deinterlace=1", "--video-filter=deinterlace", "--deinterlace-mode=blend" };
  libVLC = new LibVLC(options);
```

but it does not work when passed as Media options.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean `:deinterlace=1` ? You wrote `deinterface`. Also, please send the logs with your question.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the typo. I changed it to ":deinterlace=1"but it still does not work. VLC log shows "main Debug: deinterlace -1, mode auto, is_needed 0".